# Broken vector drawable with android fillType = evenOdd

Tags: android, svg, vector, android-vectordrawable

```
android:fillType="evenOdd"
```

make the vectror drawable broken on Android 21 is there anyway we can fix this vector?

I also decompile the release.apk and found that they remove `android:fillType="evenOdd"` and even on debug.apk it has
    `android:fillType="evenOdd"` but still show the broken image on app

Comment: `fillType` is API24+, so it is naturally ignored by any version bellow that.

Comment: after reverse it will change pathData and **remove android:fillType**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update 2021 Solution0 from  Zach Sperske

In your defaultConfig in build.gradle vectorDrawables { useSupportLibrary = true } implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0")

**Solution 1**

Flattern image in [Sketch](https://www.sketchapp.com/) and use [this site](http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/) to convert SVG to xml for Android

**Solution 2**

I use nonZero instead of evenOdd and open it in Sketch to reverse Order after reverse it will change pathData and remove android:fillType and everything work fine on Android 21+.

**Solution 3**

PNG

TLDR

After some research I found that there are two fill-rule property methods for Vector graphics, SVGs, the “evenodd” vs “nonzero”

I opened the SVG icon in Sketch and inspected the hole at the top of the icon. As expected it uses fill-rule:evenodd property. Now I have to change the fill-rule to use “nonzero” property. How? Select the path. In the right side, there is a settings icon at the “Fills” property. Click it and choose “non-zero”.

From the main menu, choose Layer → Paths → Reverse Order. I got the hole back at the top of the icon and got the hole in the app, too.

[For more detail](https://medium.com/thoughts-overflow/the-mystery-of-the-disappearing-holes-a-gripping-tale-of-using-svg-in-android-442f6035a452)

Comment: I believe there is a better solution now:
In your defaultConfig in build.gradle

vectorDrawables {
      useSupportLibrary = true
    }

implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0")

Comment: @ZachSperske added your solution with credit to you